# React native router flux Reset Stack when change Tab

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I word on react-native-router-flux and I have a problem ... I am reset my Stack navigation when I am changing of Tab navigation.
I try with backToInitial but I need to press two times on my tab for reset my stack ... I don't understand why.

My navigation :

```
-OSU
  -Scarlet
  -Gray
-VU
  -Blue
  -Black
```

So when I am on Blue and I press one time on OSU I when to access at Scarlet not gray

My code :

```
export default class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Tabs
                  key="tabbar"
                  tabBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }}
                  backToInitial={true}
                >

                  <Scene key="osu" title="OSU" icon={TabIcon} type='reset' backToInitial={true}>

                    <Scene 
                      key="scarlet"
                      component={ScarletScreen}
                      title="Scarlet"
                    />
                    <Scene
                      key="gray"
                      component={GrayScreen}
                      title="Gray"
                    />
                  </Scene>

                  <Scene key="vu" title="VU" icon={TabIcon} backToInitial={true}>

                    <Scene 
                      key="blue"
                      component={BlueScreen}
                      title="Blue"
                    />
                    <Scene
                      key="black"
                      component={BlackScreen}
                      title="Black"
                    />

                  </Scene>
                </Tabs>
            </Router>
          );
    }
}
```